# transition to another library (especially in C++)

Tags: c++, linux, transition

In some cases when libraries become obsolete in Linux; the developers suggest to transition to another library. I want to know what are the steps to transitioning?

For example, my software like many others needs `libipq.h` which became obsolete. And the developer told `libipq` users to transitioning to `nfnetlink_queue` How can I get my software get working, as other these library users could?

Comment: This is an overly-broad question and cannot possibly have an answer that isn't equally broad.  The basic steps are (1) identify an alternative library, and (2) migrate code to use this other library.  There is no silver bullet that is going to migrate your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

1. add both libraries to your project.
2. gradually convert one feature after another to use the new library instead of the old one. Test each ported feature thoroughly.
3. when you ported all features to the new library, remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Similar libraries

If the libraries are similar enough, define the obsolete functions in terms of the new library's functions. Then simply replace them in the code. Once you made sure the conversion is complete, you can work on optimizing by removing unnecessary clutter and removing the wrappers.

#### Different libraries

If the libraries are too different (in terms of functionality or performance), it may be worthwhile considering redoing parts of the work. In such cases, you might want to give parts of the program a whole new structure to fit with the new library or generally think in a different way. The previous technique would in this case lead to a disaster of code designed in one way and forced to behave like another.

Comment: Is there any way to find the dependencies fast by software?

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar, dependencies on what? Are you talking about what packages need to be installed? This seems to be a completely different question that you may want to ask separately and get better answers than just my comment.

Comment: I mean dependency (of variables and functions) to the obsoleted library, to change them faster and easier.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar, I don't think there is such a tool. However, there is one trick that could do what you are looking for. In the settings of your project, remove the obsolete library (for example in a Makefile, remove `-I/path/to/obsolete/lib` and `-lname_of_obsolete_lib`) and build. Wherever you get an error, there was a dependency to the library.